# How do the standing waves in a colloidal dielectric resonator behave?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, waves, dielectric

If there is a sufficiently big dielectric difference between the suspended particles in an colloid and the corresponding liquid, as in a conventional dielectric resonator, will the dielectric particulates align themselves in with the formed standing waves nodes or anti-nodes?